# Why does the script with FastAPI Asyncron not work?

Tags: python, windows, async-await, subprocess, fastapi

Does anyone have an idea why it works with one (script 1 - test script) and does not work with script 2 with FastAPI although it is actually the same.
Script 1:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, run
import subprocess
import re

string = '''
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Text
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

'''

p = run(["openssl",  "x509", "-noout", "-text"], stdout=PIPE,
        input=string, encoding='ascii')
print(p.returncode)

print(p.stdout)

uri = re.search(r"URI:(.+)\s", p.stdout)
print (uri.group(1))
```

Script 2 which doesnt work:

```
@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile):
    try:
        filebody = file.file.read()
        cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(filebody)
        sn = cert.serial_number
        p = run(["openssl",  "x509", "-noout", "-text"], stdout=PIPE,
                input=filebody, encoding='ascii')

        uri = re.search(r"URI:(.+)\s", p.stdout)
        url = uri.group(1)
        return {"Response": f'{p.stdout}'}
        
    except Exception as exc:
        return {'exception': f'{exc}'}
```

I think it is an async error but the terminal says nothing

Comment: you catch the Exception and send it to the client instead of dumping it - what does it say?

Comment: {"exception":"[WinError 2] The system cannot find the specified file"}

Comment: `openssl` probably isn't available where you're running FastAPI

Comment: Is there anything i can do?

Comment: find out why - you could inspect the environment by adding more to the response

Comment: what should i add for example and how, could you show me a code? :)